# Tridion Outbound Email - Adding a name to the from address of the mailer

Tags: outbound-email

I am using the outbound email to send mailers to the users. Whenever a mail is sent to user based on possibly the outlook or mailbox setting the **from** field is sometimes showing the email address that i used in the mailer page in CMS. sometime it is showing the name of email based on address book. Is there any setting which I can use to give an explicit name to the from field of the mailer. I checked the From field of the mailer it is not showing up.

E.g. I want to show the name "Newsletter" for the email abc@domain.com

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "From" field on a Mailing is the 'friendly' name that will normally be displayed in an e-mail client. If you enter "Newsletter" in that field and leave the "E-mail sender address" as the e-mail address, you will get the behavior that you are asking for.

If someone has added that e-mail address to their own address book and their e-mail client decides to show a custom name instead of what you specify, there's nothing you can do about that. But hey, they chose to use that name instead so you can't force your will on them :)